# Error 500 on Web Application Proxy for Non-claims based application

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory, reverse-proxy, adfs3.0

I am configuring Windows Active Directory SSO I built a Lab according to the tutorial here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280943.aspx

After setting the lab, I am connecting from an external client using internet explorer:

- The claims-based webapp is working perfectly fine
- I have a problem with the non-claims-based webpage (IIS startpage with windows authentication)

The authentication page appears

[image: Authentication page]

After login, I am redirected to a HTTP 500 error page.

[image: 500 Error page]

The URL worked fine from internal network, without using the Web App Proxy.

Is there someone that could help me to solve this issue?

Wishing you pleasant day

P.S: You can find the the lab diagram and configurations details and screenshots below

**Windows 2012 R2 Domain controller + DNS Server**

- IP: 192.168.22.1
- Domain: contoso.com
- Trusting computer WAP for authentication delegation (192.168.22.15) for specified SPNs: HTTP/WAP and HTTP/WAP.contoso.com

**Windows 2012 R2 Active Directory Federation Service**

- IP: 192.168.22.2
- Domain: contoso.com
- Federation URL: adfs1.contoso.com
- Relying Party trust: Non Claim aware, iddentifier: webapp2.contoso.com, issuance authorization "Permit Access to all users"

**Windows 2012 R2 IIS Server**

- IP: 192.168.22.20
- Non-claims aware application
- URL: webapp2.contoso.com
- Domain: contoso.com
- SPNs: HTTP/WEBAPP2 and HTTP/WEBAPP2.contoso.com

**Windows 2012 R2 Web Application proxy**

- IP: 192.168.22.15
- IP External: 10.0.0.1
- SPN: HTTP/WAP and HTTP/WAP.contoso.com
- Using the Non claim aware relying party trust
- Frontend and Backend URL: webapp2.contoso.com
- Backend SPN: HTTP/WEBAPP2.contoso.com

**External Client**

- IP: 10.0.0.2

Host file

```
10.0.0.1 webapp2.contoso.com
10.0.0.1 adfs1.contoso.com
10.0.0.1 enterpriseregistration.contoso.com
```

Diagram

[image: Diagram]

Web App Proxy config

[image: Web App Proxy config]

ADFS Config

[image: AFDS Config]

IIS Config

[image: IIS Config]

Client config

[image: Client config]

DC Config

[image: DC Config]

DNS Config

[image: DNS Config]

Comment: If you check Event logs on Web App Proxy are are likely to observe the following:
* Web Application Proxy encountered an unexpected error while processing the request. Error: The access code is invalid.
 (0x8007000c).
* Web Application Proxy exceeded the maximum number of permitted Kerberos authentication attempts to the backend server.
* Web Application Proxy cannot authenticate the user because the backend server responds to Kerberos authentication attempts with an HTTP 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

Technet articles are a bit vague about correct SPN entries.

Try checking for duplicates using:

```
setspn -X
```

Also you can check Event Log:

- WAP server in 'Remote Access' section. It would give you an idea which step of the communication fails.
- AD server, enable Kerberos logging first.

As a last resort you can use WireShare or Message Analyzer to sniff through network traffic and see what's wrong with the communication.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparentlty a WAP/kerberso issue. you need to restart the WAP server in KCD mode.

Answer (score 0):

In your DC Config screen, it looks like you are editing the WAP server properties to delegate to the WAP SPNs. For constrained kerberos delegation you should be delegating to the webapp2 spn on your webapp2 server.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn280943(v=ws.11) for a good example to follow.